# How to vertically align text inside a textarea inside a flexbox inside a grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I want to center text inside a textarea inside a flexbox inside a grid. I tried hard to achieve this, but it seems to be impossible (for me). Fiddle:

```js
// Prepare Filters Global Display
  const myDocumentAreaFiltersGlobalDisplay = document.getElementById("document_area_filters_global_display_id")

  const myFiltersGlobalDisplayWrap = document.createElement("div");
  myFiltersGlobalDisplayWrap.classList.add("myFiltersGlobalDisplayWrap");

  // myFiltersGlobalDisplay = document.getElementById("filters_global_display_id");
  const myFiltersGlobalDisplay = document.createElement("textarea");
  myFiltersGlobalDisplay.classList.add("myFiltersGlobalDisplay");
  myFiltersGlobalDisplay.value = "CENTER ME PLEASE";

  myFilterGlobalResetButton = document.createElement("button");
  myFilterGlobalResetButton.textContent = "X";
  myFiltersGlobalDisplayWrap.appendChild(myFiltersGlobalDisplay);
  myFiltersGlobalDisplayWrap.appendChild(myFilterGlobalResetButton);

  myDocumentAreaFiltersGlobalDisplay.appendChild(myFiltersGlobalDisplayWrap);
```

```css
/* Grid Layout */
.document_grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "document_area_filters_global_display";
}

html,
body,
.document_grid {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

textarea {
  border: 1 px solid grey;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.myFiltersGlobalDisplayWrap{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.myFiltersGlobalDisplay{
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="document_area_filters_global_display" id="document_area_filters_global_display_id"></div>
```

The height of the textarea should be for one line of text. The button on the right of the textarea should have the same height as the textarea.

Comment: you set `text-align:right` on class `.myFiltersGlobalDisplay`. Set `text-align:center`.

Comment: *"The height of the textarea should be for one line of text."* Then why not just use a text input?

Comment: And all that JavaScript just obfuscates the HTML structure. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I don't use much html generally and it was not my intention to confuse anybody with about 10 lines of standard code for DOM manipulation. I also provided a running snippet to make it easy for anybody to comprehend and understand my code.  My Opinion: It seems to me that some downvoters don't want to understand, they just want to keep an eye on the rules and teach others - in other words: Their intention is not to help but to blame.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came to the conclusion that a textarea is'nt the right choice if you want to center text vertical.

So I changed from textarea to div. I also changed from flexbox layout to full grid layout to be more consistent with the layout of parent sections.
In the following snippet the content in the div is editable and the div will grow automatically depending on the text length.

```css
.color_green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.document_area_filters_global_display {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "filter_global_area reset_button_area";
}

.myFiltersGlobalDisplayWrap{
  grid-area: filter_global_area;
}

.myFiltersGlobalDisplay{
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: right;
}

.myFilterGlobalResetButtonWrap{
  grid-area: reset_button_area;
  height: 100%;
  justify-self: end;
  align-self: center;
}

.myFilterGlobalResetButton{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="document_area_filters_global_display" id="document_area_filters_global_display_id">
  <div class="myFiltersGlobalDisplayWrap color_green">
    <div id="filters_global_display_id" class="myFiltersGlobalDisplay" contentEditable="true">Center me</div>
  </div>
  <div class="myFilterGlobalResetButtonWrap">
    <button class="myFilterGlobalResetButton" id="filters_global_display_reset_button_id">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```